# How to list objects that have the same ForeignKey attribute?

Tags: python, django

I want to list all approval steps that have the same `approval_id` on one page. I can list every `ApprovalSteps` in my views but that is not what I want. For example, I have an approval object with `ApprovalProcess` id is 1. I want to list all approval steps with `approval_id` = 1 in my template. How can I do that?

**models.py**

```
class ApprovalProcess(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='starter')
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...


class ApprovalSteps(models.Model):
    approval_id = models.ForeignKey(ApprovalProcess, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    starter = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='step_starter')
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_details(request, pk):
    approval_item = get_object_or_404(ApprovalSteps, id=pk)
    return render(request, 'approval_details.html', {'approval_item': approval_item})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the related objects `ApprovalProcess` to `ApprovalSteps`, you can use [**`_set`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)).

So in your case in you template `approval_item.approval_id_set.all`:

```
{% for item in approval_item.approval_id_set.all %}
    {{ item.doc_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

in views.py:

```
approval_item.approval_id_set.all()
```

Or use [ForeignKey.related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
approval_id = models.ForeignKey(
    ApprovalProcess, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
    related_name="processes"
)
# then you can use 
approval_item.processes.all()
```

---

Also I recommend you to rename **approval_id** to **approval** because:

> Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to
> create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `approval_details` view function to

```
def approval_details(request, pk):
    approval_items_list = get_list_or_404(ApprovalSteps, approval_id=pk)
    return render(request, 'approval_details.html', {'approval_items_list': approval_items_list})
```

Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404)